# APLpy/matplotlib: Coordinate grid alpha levels for EPS quality figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy, aplpy

In the normal matplotlib axes class, it is possible to set gridlines to have a certain transparency (alpha level). I'm attempting to utilise this with the APLpy package using the following:

```
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(18,8))

gridspec_layout = gridspec.GridSpec(1,2)

gridspec_layout1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=gridspec_layout[1], hspace=0.0, wspace=0.0)

pyplot_0 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout1[0])
pyplot_1 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout1[1])
pyplot_2 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout1[2])
pyplot_3 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout1[3])
pyplot_4 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout1[4])
pyplot_5 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout1[5])
pyplot_6 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout1[6])
pyplot_7 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout1[7])
pyplot_8 = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout1[8])

M33 = aplpy.FITSFigure('myfits.fits', figure=fig, subplot=list(gridspec_layout[0].get_position(fig).bounds), dimensions=[0, 1], slices=[0])

M33 = aplpy.FITSFigure('myfits.fits')
M33.show_grid()
M33.set_grid_alpha(0.1)

pyplot.savefig('myeps.eps', format='eps', dpi=800, clobber=True)
```

So the transparency is very high and very subtle. However, when I save the plot as an .eps format file, the transparency is lost and my lines are white. In normal matplotlib, I usually use:

```
ax.set_rasterized(True)
```

Such that the transparency kind of looks as it should.

I was wondering if there were an equivalent for the aplpy.FITSFigure class...?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can look at `fig.axes` to get a list of the `Axes` it contains.

Answer (score 0):

In the save function, there is an optional argument, transparent.  transparent is set to False by default.  If you set it to True, the transparency should be preserved when you save.

So it should be something like:

```
M33.save(filename, transparent=True, ..)
```

ETA: In the comments below it was pointed out that the EPS format does not support transparency, so the above code will not work if you're saving in that format.

Comment: I'm using a slightly more complicated figure plotting routine than the basic 1x1 plot. I tried this to no luck. Should I include my gridspec layout?

Comment: Sure, include the gridspec layout.  Are you setting the dpi?

Comment: Yes. I'll include everything I think is possibly relevant

Comment: Tihs won't work with eps (which does not support transparency at all).